# How to align text vertically equal top CSS

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align the text vertically equal using css, but there is some sort of space in the right side span.

Have added the code and fiddle link.

```css
p{
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
}
span.blue{
  background: blue;
}
span.green{
  background: green;
}
span.black{
  background: black;
}
span.circle{
      width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 12px;
    /* float: left; */
    vertical-align: top;
}
span.desc{
      /* float: left; */
    width: 115px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
     <span class="blue circle"></span>
     <span class="desc">Blue text</span>
  </p>
  
  <p>
     <span class="green circle"></span>
     <span class="desc">Green text</span>
  </p>
  
  <p>
     <span class="black circle"></span>
     <span class="desc">black text</span>
  </p>

</div>
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/3GMjp/803/)

Comment: Your dots are height: 15px and your text is height 18px, aligned top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: middle` or you can use the same `line-height` and `font-size` to solve the issue as in the snippet below.

```
p span {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

**Explanation:**

Keeping the same `line-height` and `font-size` will ensure that `vertical-align: top` will work perfectly fine.

snippet below:

```css
p{
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
}
span.blue{
  background: blue;
}
span.green{
  background: green;
}
span.black{
  background: black;
}
span.circle{
      width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 12px;
    /* float: left; */
    vertical-align: top;
}
span.desc{
      /* float: left; */
    width: 115px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
p span {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
     <span class="blue circle"></span>
     <span class="desc">Blue text</span>
  </p>
  
  <p>
     <span class="green circle"></span>
     <span class="desc">Green text</span>
  </p>
  
  <p>
     <span class="black circle"></span>
     <span class="desc">black text</span>
  </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I see the small misalignment you're talking about. Is this better ? I aligned both the cirlce and the text using

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

instead of

```
vertical-align: top;
```

**Edit**

As `vertical-align: top` has to be kept, I instead added a `margin-top: 2px` to the circles. This places them at the same height as the text and both are still aligned at top.

```css
p{
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
}
span.blue{
  background: blue;
}
span.green{
  background: green;
}
span.black{
  background: black;
}
span.circle{
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 12px;
    /* float: left; */
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
span.desc{
      /* float: left; */
    width: 115px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
     <span class="blue circle"></span>
     <span class="desc">Blue text</span>
  </p>
  
  <p>
     <span class="green circle"></span>
     <span class="desc">Green text</span>
  </p>
  
  <p>
     <span class="black circle"></span>
     <span class="desc">black text</span>
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Vertical align middle will always keeps the left side circle span in the center. But I need the text should be always intact to the text from the top

Comment: @M-S Ok, I corrected my answer taking this into account.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks to be that the height of the text is greater then that of the circle.  Flexbox could help with this, make the p display flex and set the circles to align center.

```
p{
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}
span.blue{
  background: blue;
}
span.green{
  background: green;
}
span.black{
  background: black;
}
span.circle{
  align-self:center;
      width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 12px;
    /* float: left; */
    vertical-align: top;
}
span.desc{
      /* float: left; */
    width: 115px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```